# Getting syntax error when using foreach in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my controller and I'm getting syntax error when using foreach in controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;

class course_controller extends Controller {

    public function show_details() {
        $prospects = DB::table('prospect')->get();

        foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
            DB::table('course_prospect')->insert(['prospect_id' => 
$prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested])
        };

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add semi-colon after insert method.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;

class course_controller extends Controller {

    public function show_details() {
        $prospects = DB::table('prospect')->get();

        foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
            DB::table('course_prospect')->insert(['prospect_id' => 
$prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested]);   // add semicolon here
        }   // don't need semi-colon here

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function show_details() {
    $prospects = DB::table('prospect')->get();

    foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
        DB::table('course_prospect')->insert(['prospect_id' =>
            $prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested]); //Add semicolon here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced a semicolon, check here:

```
foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
            DB::table('course_prospect')->insert(['prospect_id' => 
$prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested])
        }; <-- this one
```

Change it to:

```
foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
            DB::table('course_prospect')->insert(['prospect_id' => 
$prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested]);
        }
```

and this is not a great idea to trigger a insert query on every iteration, instead create an array and save it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
        DB::table('course_prospect')->insert(array('prospect_id' => $prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon(`;`) is missing in your `insert` Query:

```
foreach ($prospects as $prospect){  
   DB::table('course_prospect')->insert([  
      'prospect_id' => $prospect->id,
      'course_id'   => $prospect->course_intrested 
   ]); //You missed the semicolon here
} //remove semicolon from here
```

The syntax for [insert method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts) for inserting records into the database

The Syntax for foreach:

```
foreach($prospects as $prospect){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced the `;` and that caused the issue

And also I'm recommending you to use the associated model instead of `DB` just like below

```
use App/Prospect;
use App/CourseProspect;

class course_controller extends Controller {

    public function show_details() {
        $prospects = Prospect::all();

        foreach ($prospects as $prospect) {
            CourseProspect::create([['prospect_id' => 
$prospect->id, 'course_id' => $prospect->course_intrested]]);
        };
    }
}
```